# Como publicar uma API escrita em Typescript no NPMjs?

Tags: node.js, gulp, typescript, npm

Eu criei uma API em Typescript, a pouco tempo.

E gostaria de saber como publica-lá no NPMjs, sei que tem como publicar porque o Angular 2 baixa libs em Typescript.

Não sei que etapas devo seguir para publicar. Não achei nem exemplos..

Obrigado!

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/

Comment: Na documentação, não fala a respeito do Typescript.